# Zabbix 5 - Can an item be monitored only at certain circumstance?

Tags: triggers, dependencies, monitor, zabbix

I am using Zabbix 5. As long as I know, there are item dependencies and trigger dependencies.
Other than that, I am curious if I can set a condition for an item to be monitored only at that condition.
For example, if one firewall device gives 0 ping back, then I want to start monitoring (or sending pings) to a L2 device which is above that firewall device. So, my L2 device will be monitored not all the time but only when I get a trigger. Is there such functionality available in Zabbix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not natively. Actually I don't see the usefulness for a "light dependancy" like that.

However, a possible workaround:

- create the L2 device item (ping, tcp port etc..) and disable it.
- create a custom action for FW unreachability to launch a custom script, for both problem creation and problem resolution
- the script should do an api call to enable/disable the L2 device item

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that. Also, your advice is a lot helpful.I will try that approach.

Comment: This could be a tmi but I have thousands of devices(FW) to monitor and I do not want to waste cpu or memory to keep track of another thousands of devices(L2) connected to the FWs 24/7. This is the reason I want to turn on and off monitoring certain items.

Comment: Well, if you ping 1000 devices with a 1 minute interval we're talking of less than 20 nvps. Assuming 1728000 new values per day with an average of 90 bytes per item we get 150MB of storage per day per check, that's not much in your infrastructure has thousands of devices.

Comment: 150MB does not sound too much but I actually have 7000 (FW) devices right now and want to ping another 7000 (L2) devices to clearly figure out the origin of problems.